# Is the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{(k+1)\log (k+1)}$ convergent to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Is it true that $$ \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{(k+1)\log(k+1)} \to 0$$
>   as $n\to \infty$?

It is clear that

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{(k+1)\log(k+1)}\le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{\log(k+1)}
$$

So if we didn't have that "$\log$" term the statement would be false. But I can't think of a good approximation to the term $k/\log(k+1)$ to proceed further from here. None of the standard theorems I know of seem to apply too.

I highly suspect the sequence does converge to $0$, from the context where it was derived. Any good ideas to proceed from here?

Thanks

Comment: How about using the Cesáro-Stolz theorem? This is a discrete analogue of the L'hôpital's rule.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee I think it does work, with $a_n$ as the sum and $b_n=n^2$ with where $a_n,b_n$ come from this:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem

Comment: See my answer. What makes it work is that $\log k$ is within a factor of 2 of $\log n$ for almost all $k$.

Answer (score 3):

Arguing a little sloppily,
where "$\sim$" means
"within a factor of",

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{(k+1)\log(k+1)}
&\sim \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{k^2}{k\log(k)}
\qquad\text{since we can ignore }k=1\\
&\sim \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{k}{\log(k)}\\
&\sim \frac{1}{n^2\log(n)}\sum_{k=2}^n k
\qquad\text{since }\log k > \frac12 \log n \text{ for }k > \sqrt{n}\\
&\sim \frac{1}{\log(n)}\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore it does converge to zero.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you chose $\sqrt{n}$, say, instead of $n^{1/3}$? Is it just because $1/2$ is sufficient?

Comment: Yes. The $\sqrt$ keeps almost all the terms  and rhe log keeps it within a factor of 2.